# Calculate Various Centrality using Boost Library

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I am new to C++. Is there any way of calculating the [Closeness Centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Closeness_centrality), [Betweenness Centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Betweenness_centrality) and [Degree Centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Degree_centrality) of a graph using the Boost graph library?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Boost Graph Library only does [Betweenness](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/betweenness_centrality.html) (part of [Graph Metrics](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html)):

> [the algorithm] can operate either on weighted graphs (if a suitable edge weight map is supplied) or unweighted graphs (if no edge weight map is supplied). The result is the absolute betweenness centrality;

See [How to calculate betweenness using boostlib for adjacency list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7706391/3235496) and [Yet another BGL's Betweenness centrality issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23144312/3235496) for examples.